# Find the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

[image]

My idea: how to make a connection between this with isomorphism.

Comment: Given a quotient of elements in $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ you get an element of $Q[\sqrt 2]$ by multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: can we replace root of 2 with any number outside Q.  @Dane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ because $\sqrt 2$ is algebraic.

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2$.

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is thus the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\mathbb Z$ and $\sqrt 2$.

Hence, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.

More generally, by the same argument, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic number, then $\mathbb Q[\alpha]=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and is the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.